# systemd messages not showing in /var/log/messages

Tags: logging, fedora, syslog, rsyslog, systemd

systemd version is systemd-201-2.fc18.9.i686
journald is masked.
rsyslog version is rsyslog-7.2.6

I see all messages logs coming in /var/log/messages except for systemd messages.
I see systemd messages in dmesg buffer but not in /var/log/messages.

in /etc/systemd/system.conf also I have
"LogTarget=syslog-or-kmsg"

Still not able to see any systemd messages in /var/log/messages.
Can somebody please help and also explain what exactly syslog-or-kmsg means, I cannot find a good explanation on this.

Here is the content of rsyslog.service

at /usr/lib/systemd/system/rsyslog.service

```
[Unit]
Description=System Logging Service

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/rsyslog
ExecStart=/sbin/rsyslogd -n
Sockets=syslog.socket
StandardOutput=null

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
Alias=syslog.service
```

content of /etc/sysconfig/rsyslog

```
# NOTE NOTE NOTE NOTE NOTE
#
# This file is AUTO-GENERATED based on the system's configuration.
# Any modifications you make to this file will be lost when the
# system's configuration is changed, e.g. from the CLI.
#

SYSLOGD_OPTIONS=""

# End of auto-generated file
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure on Fedora specifically but they say, there is a file called `journald.conf` and setting in it: `ForwardToSyslog=no` since `systemd` version 216. This setting is set for `rsyslog/syslog-ng` since version 3.6 due to it will fetch messages from socket `/run/systemd/journal/syslog`.

Comment: Hmm... but I have already masked journald service and using rsyslog directly.